# Upsample pandas DataFrame with integer multiple of current frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I need to upsample a data frame such that there are integer steps (roughly) evenly-spaced between the current indices (which are evenly-spaced to begin with). Specifically, I have annual data and I want to resample so that there are 14 rows spaced between each current row. These will later be filled in with interpolation.

Here's an example dataframe to better illustrate the issue:

```
              A           B         C
1980-01-01    0    1.000000 -0.871623
1981-01-01   25    3.162278 -0.186602
etc...
```

What I want is a method to resample so that I get something like this

```
              A           B         C
1980-01-01    0    1.000000 -0.871623
1980-02-01  NaN         NaN       NaN
1980-03-01  NaN         NaN       NaN
1980-04-01  NaN         NaN       NaN
1980-05-01  NaN         NaN       NaN
1980-06-01  NaN         NaN       NaN
1980-07-01  NaN         NaN       NaN
1980-08-01  NaN         NaN       NaN
1980-09-01  NaN         NaN       NaN
1980-10-01  NaN         NaN       NaN
1980-11-01  NaN         NaN       NaN
1980-12-01  NaN         NaN       NaN
1981-01-01   25    3.162278 -0.186602
```

But with dates that divide the year roughly evenly into 15 intervals (instead of being constrained to pandas frequencies like this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution which works, provided you don't mind converting the index from datetime format. I'm sure that it is possible to convert back to datetime format, but in my case this isn't necessary. Here's an example of the process (assuming you have a dataframe `df` which has a datetime index):

```
n_intervals = 15
delta       = 1.0 / n_intervals
base_index  = df.index.year
df.index    = base_index
new_index   = np.arange(base_index.min(), base_index.max()+delta, delta)

df = df.reindex(new_index, tolerance=0.000001, method='nearest')
df.interpolate('cubic', inplace=True)
```